# How can I save an item from each loop?

Tags: java, logic

I apologize for my question not being very clear, I'll attempt to explain it through my code.

**The entire code:**

```
package realestatepropvalue;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class RealEstatePropValueA3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Hello friend, you will enter a series "
            + "of fields that'll calculate your Real Estate Property Value.");

    System.out.print("Please enter a Street Number ");
    String streetnum = sc.next();
    sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("You entered the Street Number, " + streetnum);

    System.out.print("Please enter a Street Name ");
    String streetnam = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("You entered the Street Name, " + streetnam + " ");

    System.out.print("Please enter the number of rooms! (Up to 5!) ");

    int roomcount = sc.nextInt();

    String[] places = new String[roomcount];
    for (int i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
        places[i] = "Place Number: " + (i + 1);
    }

    sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("You said that there were " + roomcount + " rooms!");

    System.out.println("What is the price per sq. feet?");
    int pricePer = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine(); //This will consume the end of the line.


    System.out.print("Please enter the types of rooms (up to " + roomcount + ") that fill up the " + roomcount + " rooms!\n"
            + "(Rooms like Living, Dining, Bedroom1-2, Kitchen, Bathroom, etc!) \n ");
    int squareCounter = 0;
    String[] types = new String[roomcount];

    for (int i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Please enter the types of room " + places[i] + ": ");
        String roomName = sc.nextLine();
        types[i] = roomName;

        System.out.print("Please enter the square feet of " + roomName + ": ");
        int squareFeet = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine(); //This will consume empty line.

        squareCounter = squareFeet + squareCounter;

        System.out.println("Room name: " + roomName + " is: " + squareFeet + "square feet.");


        int finalCalc = pricePer * squareCounter;




        System.out.println("\n"); // make space for a cleaner format
        System.out.println("1.                   \t      Street: " + streetnam + " #" + streetnum);
        System.out.println("2.                   \t Total Rooms: " + roomcount);
        System.out.println("3.                   \t  Total Area: " + squareCounter + "sq. ft.");
        System.out.println("4.           \t    Price per sq. ft: " + pricePer);
        System.out.println("5.   \t    Estimated property value: " + finalCalc + "\n");
    }



    // TODO code application logic here
}//main

}//class RealEstatePropValueA3
```

The output:

```
Hello friend, you will enter a series of fields that'll calculate your Real Estate Property Value.
Please enter a Street Number 7 **<-- user input**
You entered the Street Number, 7
Please enter a Street Name Washington Street **<-- user input**
You entered the Street Name, Washington Street 
Please enter the number of rooms! (Up to 5!) 2 **<-- user input**
You said that there were 2 rooms!
What is the price per sq. feet?
150 **<-- user input**
Please enter the types of rooms (up to 2) that fill up the 2 rooms!
(Rooms like Living, Dining, Bedroom1-2, Kitchen, Bathroom, etc!) 
 Please enter the types of room Place Number: 1: Kitchen **<-- user input**
Please enter the square feet of Kitchen: 15 **<-- user input**
Room name: Kitchen is: 15square feet.


1.                            Street: Washington Street #7
2.                       Total Rooms: 2
3.                        Total Area: 15sq. ft.
4.                  Price per sq. ft: 150
5.          Estimated property value: 2250

Please enter the types of room Place Number: 2: enter code here **this is where I'd continue**
```

**The desired output:**

```
1.                            Street: Washington Street #7
2.                       Total Rooms: 2 (All entered rooms would output here)
3.                        Total Area: 15sq. ft.
4.                  Price per sq. ft: 150
5.          Estimated property value: 2250
```

I just need help somehow collecting all the users entered rooms, and have them be outputted on number 2 (in parenthesis.)

Also the assignment requests that " Your program should keep the line count in a separate variable and print the line numbers in your report using that variable as shown: " Though I did that manually... which I know is wrong.

How could I achieve this? I don't understand how to translate this into java code. I'm very new to this, thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with you should be declaring variable that hold monetary values with a float or double data type. Also variables dealing with square footage should also be declared as float or double. These variables would be **pricePer**, **finalCalc**, **squareFeet**, and **squarecCounter**. You should also be using the **Scanner.nextDouble()** method when gathering information from the User to fill any of those variables. You will get more accurate overall calculations.

A max room count of **5** is unrealistic. There should be no limit on rooms. Allow the User to determine this maximum. You just need to ensure each room is processed through your **for** loop.

Your final console display which shows the overall results should be done **after** your **for** loop for processing the rooms.

Your code may look something like this when done:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Hello friend, you will enter a series "
        + "of fields that'll calculate your Real Estate Property Value.");

System.out.print("Please enter a address Home Number (ex. 12345): ");
String streetnum = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("You entered the Home Number: " + streetnum);

System.out.print("Please enter a Street Name: ");
String streetnam = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("You entered the Street Name, " + streetnam);

System.out.print("Please enter the number of rooms: ");
int roomcount = sc.nextInt();
String[] rooms = new String[roomcount];
for (int i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++) {
    rooms[i] = "Room Number: " + (i + 1);
}
sc.nextLine();

System.out.println("You said that there were " + roomcount + " rooms!");

System.out.println("What is the price per sq. feet?");
double pricePer = sc.nextDouble();
sc.nextLine(); //This will consume the end of the line.

System.out.println("Please enter the room names (up to " + roomcount + ") that make up the home!\n"
        + "(Rooms like Living, Dining, Bedroom1-2, Kitchen, Bathroom, etc!)\n");
double squareCounter = 0.0;
double finalCalc = 0.0;
String[] roomNames = new String[roomcount];

for (int i = 0; i < roomNames.length; i++) {
    System.out.print("Please enter the name of room " + rooms[i] + ": ");
    String roomName = sc.nextLine();
    roomNames[i] = roomName;
    System.out.print("Please enter the square feet of " + roomName + ": ");
    double squareFeet = sc.nextDouble();
    sc.nextLine(); //This will consume empty line.
    squareCounter = squareFeet + squareCounter;
    System.out.println("Room name: " + roomName + " is: " + squareFeet + " square feet.\n");
}

finalCalc = pricePer * squareCounter;
System.out.println("\n"); // make space for a cleaner format
System.out.println("1.                   \t      Street: " + streetnam + " #" + streetnum);
System.out.println("2.                   \t Total Rooms: " + roomcount);
System.out.println("3.                   \t  Total Area: " + squareCounter + " sq. ft.");
System.out.println("4.           \t    Price per sq. ft: " + 
        NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "US")).format(pricePer));
System.out.println("5.   \t    Estimated property value: " +
        NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "US")).format(finalCalc) + "\n");
```